# PHP date format converting

Tags: php, date

Here is what I have:

```
$dateFormat = 'M d, Y';
$dateString = 'January 23, 2010';
```

What I need is a timestamp of `$dateString` so I can do this:

```
$newFormattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

I tried to use `strtotime` function but it tries to find out the format itself and doesn't work always. In my situation I know both the date string and date format.

How can I set `$timestamp` to an appropriate value for use with the [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function?

EDIT: I need this to work in both Linux and Windows environments.

EDIT: The solution must support PHP version 4 or higher

EDIT: MySQL has a function called [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) which takes a date string and a date format and returns `Y-m-d` formatted date string. Any equivalent function for php works for me also.

Answer (score 7):

As of PHP5.3 you can use the DateTime API

```
$dt = date_create_from_format('M d, Y', 'January 23, 2010');
echo date_timestamp_get($dt);
```

or with OOP notation

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y', 'January 23, 2010');
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

Note that while `DateTime` is available in PHP < 5.3, the methods used above are not and while you could simulate `->getTimestamp()` with `->format('U')`, there is no easy workaround for `createFromFormat()`

An alternative would be to use [`Zend_Date`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html) from Zend Framework:

```
$date = new Zend_Date('Feb 31, 2007', 'MM.dd.yyyy');
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the answer but I need this to work in PHP 4 or higher. I have added this requirement to question also.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strptime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php), [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [`strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

```
$ftime = strptime($dateString, $dateFormat);
$timestamp = mktime($ftime['tm_hour'], $ftime['tm_min'], $ftime['tm_sec'], 1,
                    $ftime['tm_yday'] + 1, $ftime['tm_year'] + 1900);

echo strftime('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Please note that `strptime` is not implemented on Windows platforms.

Note that the arguments to `mktime` are somewhat unusual - `strptime` returns a day of the year (between 0-365, inclusive) rather than a day of the month and a month, so we set the month parameter to `mktime` to 1, and add 1 to the day of the year. Also, `strptime` returns years since 1900 for the year value it returns, so we need to add 1900 to the year before passing it through to `mktime`.

Also, you might want to check whether `$ftime` is `FALSE` before passing it into `mktime`. `strptime` returning `FALSE` denotes that the inputs `$dateString` is not a valid date format according to `$dateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks Dominic but in the php manaul of strptime it says "This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.". This is a killer for me.

Comment: There's also `strtotime` that helps.

Comment: Hi Henasraf, as i have explained in my question, strtotime doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Ah - OK. I'll leave this answer here in case it's useful to someone else. In future, if you've got platform limitations, it might be worth stating them in the question :-)

Comment: +1 for the mention of `strptime` not beeing implemented on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Given my understanding of the question and what is available in PHP, you need to relax your expectations somewhere or other.

A 'simple' solution (which has already been discounted) would be to force using PHP 5.3 and the tools available in it.

A less simple solution would be to take those additions and port them over to PHP-land (with PHP 4 compatibility, good luck).

Another route of exploration would be to consider the occasions where `strtotime` does not work for you and working around those limitations.

How widely variant are your format strings? It may be possible to come up with a solution mapping format strings to functions/methods (to do that date parsing) providing they're pretty restricted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateFormat = 'M d, Y'
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);
echo date($dateFormat, $timestamp);
```

if i haven't misunderstand your question you can try the code above..