# Function to parse date to parts

Tags: php, date, formatting, string-formatting

Is there any nice function in PHP to parse the date into parts given the specified format?

e.g.

```
some_function('20112000', 'dmY') 
some_function('2000-11-20', 'Y-m-d')
some_function('2000 text 11-20', 'Y text m-d')
```

`array('d'=>20, 'm'=>11, 'Y'=>2000)` expected in all of the above cases,
(assuming formats compatible with `date()` function)

#### Update:

I use PHP 5.1.9
This is also possible using `Zend_Date`, but it uses different formats than `date()` (e.g. `ddMMyyyy`)

Comment: Some genius at my company connects to mysql every time he needs this functionality

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date format converting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332740/php-date-format-converting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP >= 5.3, the [**`DateTime::createFromFormat()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) allows one to parse a date according to a specified format.

After that, you get a [**`DateTime`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, and up to your to work with it in order to get the array you want.

Comment: Thanks, however, this time I have only PHP 5.1.9.

Comment: 5.1 ??? Ergh ; do you realize how old this is ? And that even PHP 5.2 has reached his end-of-support ? *(I suppose it's not your fault, but because you're on RedHat or some other distrib like that one... )*

Comment: Update! Really ;) The last 5.1 is of 2006, in the same year 5.2 were released and even 5.3 is now 2 years old.

Comment: I agree with Pascal, but it's unfortunately not _that_ long ago I had the distinct pleasure (ahum) to have to work on PHP _4_ for some client. Not always factors under our control, but indeed do complain about stuff reaching end of support (and even end of security updates), that's all that can be done in some cases.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like it either. Anyway, I have no access to 5.3 *this time*.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own:

```
function ($date, $format = array('d', 'm', 'Y')) {
    $ts = strtotime($date);
    $out = array();
    foreach ($format as $v) {
        $out[$v] = date($v, $ts);
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP < 5.3, look at the more [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/strptime). It uses `strftime` format, but is sort of what you are looking for.