# Update package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I just installed the envisag 3.x plugin from the Ubuntu Software Center, My question is, how can I update this to envisage 4.x.

I'm using python 2.6 and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit

Comment: completely off-topic here, but to give you a pointer re the question you just deleted: This answer will help if you have PHP 5.3: [Function to parse date to parts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6918740) - the reason why strtotime() didn't work is that the `DD/MM/YYYY` format is not recognized by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu packages, it may not be the latest version for 2 reasons:

1. **dependencies availability**: the dependencies version required is not available in Ubuntu yet
2. **stability**: latest version may not be the most stable version, therefore the most stable version is picked by Ubuntu

To manually update certain package to your desired version ( either upgrade / downgrade ), remove the version that comes along with Ubuntu, and download from developer. Follow the instructions to install the package. However, through this method, the package cannot update through `apt-get`.