# Converting month name in given date into month number

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP date format converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332740/php-date-format-converting)

I have a date like **2012-september-09**. How to convert this into **2012-09-09** using PHP?

Comment: i try to convert 2012-september-09 to 2012-09-09 with date("Y-m-D",strtotime("2012-september-09")). but this returns 2012-09-01. so please tell me the correct method to convert this

Comment: there is dozens of similar questions asking how to format dates. please do research them before asking questions.

Comment: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-d', '2012-september-09')->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Change 

<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2012-september-09'));?>

 To

<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('09-september-2012'));?>
```

Comment: k.. it returns the month number, how to return the year and date from above php function

Comment: this will give 2012-09-01. The OP already said so in the comments.

Comment: ya i have checked this.. Please change the string to

Comment: My assumption would be the OP cannot change the string because if s/he could s/he could simply change it to the desired output format and wouldn't have to ask for a programmatic solution.

Comment: @Ialith if this answer solved your question why did you have to ask the question in the first place? Your question makes absolutely no sense if the solution is to change the format.

Comment: thanks, i got the result

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `strptime`

```
$date = '2012-september-09';
$strp = strptime($date, '%Y-%B-%d');
$ymd = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $strp['tm_year'] + 1900, $strp['tm_mon'] + 1, $strp['tm_mday']);
$new_date = new DateTime($ymd);
echo $new_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

here's a [Codepad](http://codepad.org/tZhouv2x)

Comment: Condition is that you have no Windows platform. But this is a good solution.